# Why is std::find implemented this way?

Tags: c++, stl, std

I happen to run into the source of `std::find` and find it confusing to me. Basically it divides the count of items by 4 and do the compare 4 in each round:

```
template<typename _RandomAccessIterator, typename _Tp>
_RandomAccessIterator
__find(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last,
   const _Tp& __val, random_access_iterator_tag)
{
  typename iterator_traits<_RandomAccessIterator>::difference_type
__trip_count = (__last - __first) >> 2;

  for (; __trip_count > 0; --__trip_count)
{
  if (*__first == __val)
    return __first;
  ++__first;

  if (*__first == __val)
    return __first;
  ++__first;

  if (*__first == __val)
    return __first;
  ++__first;

  if (*__first == __val)
    return __first;
  ++__first;
}

  switch (__last - __first)
{
case 3:
  if (*__first == __val)
    return __first;
  ++__first;
case 2:
  if (*__first == __val)
    return __first;
  ++__first;
case 1:
  if (*__first == __val)
    return __first;
  ++__first;
case 0:
default:
  return __last;
}
}
```

I have no idea why it's done this way. Looks like some optimization. But I don't think this will take advantage of multi-core that easy. This is in a single thread anyway.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like manual loop unrolling. Whence is this implementation?

Comment: For one thing, it spends less time comparing `__trip_count` to zero and more time actually comparing values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like [loop unwinding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding), also known as loop unrolling.

Answer (score 4):

It's loop unrolling. The result is the same, but it's friendlier for the processor.

The asymptotic complexity is the same though.

Answer (score 1):

Not being completely sure, I think this is kind of a loop unrolling.

See Loop unrolling in : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6154/Writing-Efficient-C-and-C-Code-Optimization

Answer (score -2):

It's [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device). It's an old optimisation technic 
which mixes while and switch statements in an special way. It uses loop unroling. In assembler you would jump right inside an unrolled loop.

Comment: It's not Duff's device, the switch statement isn't inside the loop. Quite possibly the emitted code would be smaller if it did use Duff's device, though.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I was under the impression you put duff's device at the end of the unrolled loop not inside it. Only the last iteration is going to have a non full count.

Comment: @LokiAstari: no, that's not correct. Duff's invention was specifically the (ab)use of the C switch construct to jump into the middle of an unrolled loop, where "the middle" is "the number of iterations required modulo the length of the unroll". So in fact it's the first iteration that doesn't have a full count.